# How to generate a query to capture features within a set distance of a route eg road or river

Tags: qgis, overpass-turbo, quickosm

I am attempting to create a map that shows features along the route of a river to a specified distance using the QuickOSM plug-in for QGIS.

Initially, I thought I could simply run a query using the "around" option, but this only returned features from a single point rather than the full stretch of the river.

After a bit of digging around, I found a post that suggested using points on a path. The actual post was using GPS-generated points, which I don't have, so instead I created a new layer and plotted the general path of the river. This gave me about 30-40 points which I could apply latitude and longitude to. So far so good.

From there I generated the following query and pasted it into QuickOSM:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:1000];
(
    way["water"="river"](around:10000,52.4916542, -3.74552301,
    52.46655143, -3.69056807,
    52.44771496, -3.6184397,
    52.44352799, -3.54287665,
    52.45190154, -3.4673136,
    52.50838141, -3.43640145,
    52.52092265, -3.38831587,
    52.4958366, -3.35740371,
    52.56687657, -3.21658166,
    52.65447324, -3.13758393,
    52.7314966, -3.05515151,
    52.72109598, -2.84907046,
    52.74813244, -2.80441957,
    52.71485441, -2.77007273,
    52.71901555, -2.70824842,
    52.67322116, -2.65672815,
    52.63780167, -2.625816,
    52.61695326, -2.44034306,
    52.53346031, -2.41286558,
    52.4204925, -2.36134532,
    52.35550952, -2.30295569,
    52.2694173, -2.26860885,
    52.2378783, -2.22395796,
    52.11571642, -2.23426201,
    51.99956318, -2.16900301,
    51.92760823, -2.23082733,
    51.91701688, -2.26860885,
    51.83219607, -2.28921695,
    51.8449294, -2.34073722,
    51.79822294, -2.34760658,
    51.81733598, -2.43347369,
    51.78547641, -2.45064711,
    51.77060091, -2.38882279,
    51.72807245, -2.48499395,
    51.67059549, -2.57773042
 );
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

This sort of did what I wanted, but it seems to be missing chunks of the river. I ran the same query in Overpass Turbo and got the same result.

The image below demonstrates the result with gaps in the river and includes the points I made to trace the route and generate the latitude and longitude:

[image: The result of the query showing gaps in the river]

The following image shows the actual path of the river as a comparison:

[image]

Initially, I thought it was maybe getting too much data and giving up, so I tried increasing the timeout and reducing the number of points, but each time the same features were omitted.

I also ran a simple query that collected all the matching features in the canvas extent using QuickOSM to check the features did exist under that query:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["water"="river"]( {{bbox}});
    way["water"="river"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["water"="river"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

This was successful with no omissions

What I'd like to know is how I can get all the features along the route (in this case a river)

Eventually, the intention is to build up a series of layers including roads, towns etc. but given that my query for rivers doesn't return all te rivers I am dubious that other features will come in as complete as I'd like.

Comment: In your first query, you are getting basic river areas, BUT not those formed by multipolygons. You can see this by inspecting (in say ID editor) the sections of the river adjacent to the sections you are currently receiving. I'm no Overpass expert but your query probably needs some extra logic/recursion. Might be better asked on StackExchange as that site seems to have more questions/answers relating to Overpass (overpass-api tag)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you think too complicated: the river Severn that you want to extract exists as a relation (no. 14304), see https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/14304. To download, use this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
nwr["name"="River Severn"]({{bbox}});
out geom;
```

*Showing the query and the output with [https://overpass-turbo.eu/](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1FpU)*
[image]

Here is how I identified the relation:

1. In [OpenStreetMap Website](https://www.openstreetmap.org), I zoomed in to the object (river), used the identify tool, clicked on the river to get the objects nearby, between else a part of the river line:

   [image]
2. Click on the river object in the screenshot above. In the next window, you see the link to the relation of the river:

   [image]

Comment: I understand that there is a much simpler way of just getting the river itself and this solution would be perfect for that, but what I'm after is to get features with a set distance from the river. So for instance in my original query, I'm expecting to see tributaries of the river Severn as well as the Severn itself.
Ultimately I would like to run a query that includes roads, towns etc around the river which I will include in separate layers.

Comment: OK, I see. Creating small buffers around the points you have and than iterate over the extent of these polygons would be an option?

Comment: That could work, yes. How would I go about that?